# what's wrong with the code?

Tags: php

```
  <?php if (!empty(cutstr($node->content,300))) : ?>
      <div class="pr_teaser">
       <?php echo cutstr($node->content,300); ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

what's wrong with the code? the `cutstr` function is ok.  my IDE makes an a alert to this line    `<?php if (!empty(cutstr($node->content,300))) : ?>` is wrong? but i can't find the error.

Comment: What makes you think something is wrong with it? (i.e. what output do you expect and what output do you get?)

Comment: What's definitely wrong is that you're not using `htmlspecialchars()` to escape the output.

Comment: Reading documentation helps: http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php . Note the note.

Answer (score 4):

> empty() only checks variables as
>   anything else will result in a parse
>   error. In other words, the following
>   will not work: empty(trim($name)).

From http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

You need to do something like this:

```
<?php $value=cutstr($node->content,300); if (!empty($value)) : ?>
  <div class="pr_teaser">
   <?php echo $value; ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```